# Mocha - Test fails also if it is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

This is the test code:

```
chai.assert.throws(() => {
            host1.add()
        }, TriedAddingDuplicateError)
```

As you can see, error have been thrown, Mocha got it, but the test is marked as failed anyway:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'TriedAddingDuplicateError' but 
'TriedAddingDuplicateError' was thrown
```

- Note1: As you can see, the method raising the error is an instance method
- Note2: I did try to use one other way that is `chai.expect(() => host1.add()).to.throw(TriedAddingDuplicateError)`, but the result is the same

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think this has to do with how chai assertions work internally. As I recall they use strict equality operator`===` with `throws` function. So when you compare the two errors, they are two different instances, hence the error.

It would be nice to share the implementation of the `add` function.

And, Is `TriedAddingDuplicateError` in the snippet an errorType or an instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to instanciate the error class in the function:
**host.js before**

```
add () {
    let database = db.read()

    const hostToAdd = Host.findByHost(this.host)

    if (Validation.IsEmptyObject(hostToAdd)) {
        database.hosts.push(this)
        db.write(database)

        return this
    }

    throw TriedAddingDuplicateError
}
```

**host.js now**

```
add () {
    let database = db.read()

    const hostToAdd = Host.findByHost(this.host)

    if (Validation.IsEmptyObject(hostToAdd)) {
        database.hosts.push(this)
        db.write(database)

        return this
    }

    throw new TriedAddingDuplicateError()
}
```